# Perforce streams; child streams and reuse workspace, no files visible

Tags: stream, perforce

I am setting up a very basic stream architecture, whereby I have a mainline stream and then a development stream beneath that. I want to reuse my workspace so I can move between the two, but for some reason my child stream doesn't have any files in it.
I thought that the child stream automatically inherited the paths, and all I have in my paths is the most basic 'share ...'

Wth stupid mistake am I making??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the files are `share ...`, you need to `populate` them from the parent before they appear in the child:

```
p4 populate -r -S //stream/your_dev_stream
```

Note that the `p4 switch` command (which I think is normally only available on "local" servers but you can flip a server configurable to allow it on shared servers) does this automatically.  Use `p4 switch -c your_dev_stream` to automatically create `your_dev_stream` as a child stream of your current stream within the same stream depot, populate it from the parent stream, and switch your workspace to it (shelving any pending work first).